# Build javascript async/await with webpack 2 and babel-loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, async-await, babel-loader

I'm using webpack 2.3.3 to build my node.js application with async/await javascript syntax. Transpiling is done using babel-loader 6.4.1.
My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{ (...)
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -Rf dist; webpack -p --progress --colors --display-error-details --config webpack/prod.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node dist/assets/server.js"
  },
  (...)
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.24.1",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.10.3",
    (...)
    "webpack": "2.3.3"
  },
  (...)
}
```

My webpack config uses the `transform-async-to-generator` plugin with line `loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=react&plugins[]=transform-async-to-generator', 'eslint-loader']` in config file `webpack/prod.js`:

```
'use strict';

require('babel-polyfill');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};

fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function(x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function(mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

var serverConfig = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/server'],
    target: 'node',
    externals: nodeModules,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/assets/'),
        filename: 'server.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=react&plugins[]=transform-async-to-generator', 'eslint-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = [ clientConfig, serverConfig ];
```

When I run `npm run build`, the build fails on lines containing `async function foo(arg) { (...) }` with error `Parsing error: Unexpected token function`.

When I remove the async/await code parts, the builds succeeds.

I've looked at solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067405/error-using-es7-async-await-with-node-webpack-and-babel-loader) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579395/es7-async-await-functions-with-babel-loader-not-working) but could not get the build of async/await code to work.

Can anybody help me with this? Thx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parse error happens in the `eslint-loader` because the default eslint parser does not understand `async` and `await`. You have to use `babel-eslint` as described in [Specifying Parser](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser). In your eslint config add:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

and install `babel-eslint`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. I upvoted your answer but since I'm a noob, it does not show.